# How to sort array of objects based on order of another array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an ArrayList of Strings in a certain particular order

```
ArrayList<String> sortedkeys
```

And I have an unordered set of objects

```
Set<Skugroup> unsortedSet
```

Where SkuGroup contains a key to be used for sorting

```
Class SkuGroup {
   private String sortkey;
   private String name; 
}
```

I need to copy all the SkuGroup objects into a new array in the same order of sortedSkus, where the sortedkey value is the same as the SkuGroup->sortkey

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Loop through the `sortedKeys` `List`.  For each key, retrieve the `Skugroup` from the `Set`,  Add `Skugroup` to a new `List` or `Set`.  Spell `Skugroup` consistently.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That's what I thought too. But how do I retrieve the Skugroup from the set based on the sortKey without looping through the whole set?

Comment: You have to go linearly through enough of the Set to find the Skugroup you're looking for, unless the Set is sorted.

Comment: ok that's the right idea, I determined that it's fastest if I store the set as a map so that I can retrieve the object using the key

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way would be to store the set as a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), because it keeps its elements sorted by a given comparator. To make it easier, here we can implement interface [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) on the `SkuGroup` class.

```java
class SkuGroup implements Comparable<SkuGroup> {
    private String sortKey;
    private String name;

    public String getSortKey() {
        return sortKey;
    }

    public int compareTo(SkuGroup s1) {
        return this.sortKey.trim().compareTo(s1.getSortKey().trim());
    }
}
```

```java
ArrayList<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList<>();

Set<SkuGroup> skuSet = new TreeSet<>();

/** add items to skuSet **/
```

> I need to copy all the SkuGroup objects into a new array in the same
> order of sortedSkus, where the sortedkey value is the same as the
> SkuGroup->sortkey

I assume you mean you want to transfer just the `sortKey`, and not the entire object because of the type on the ArrayList.

```java
skuSet.stream().forEach(item -> sortedKeys.add(item.getSortKey()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Expected order: c -> b -> a -> d");
        List<String> sortedkeys = Arrays.asList("c", "b", "a", "d");

        // Construct unsorted set (of course a Set has no order);
        System.out.println("Unsorted order: a -> b -> c -> d");
        Set<SkuGroup> unsortedSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
                new SkuGroup("a", "name_a"),
                new SkuGroup("b", "name_b"),
                new SkuGroup("c", "name_c"),
                new SkuGroup("d", "name_d")));

        List<SkuGroup> sortedSkuGroups = sortedkeys.stream()
                .map(key -> unsortedSet.stream()
                        .filter(skuGroup -> skuGroup.getSortKey().equals(key))
                        .findFirst()
                        .get()
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Sorted order: " + sortedSkuGroups);

        // In case if you need to convert this into Array:
        SkuGroup[] sortedSkuGroupArray = sortedSkuGroups.stream().toArray(SkuGroup[]::new);
        System.out.println("Sorted order in Array: " + Arrays.toString(sortedSkuGroupArray));
    }
}

class SkuGroup {
    private String sortKey;
    private String name;

    public SkuGroup(String sortKey, String name) {
        this.sortKey = sortKey;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSortKey() {
        return sortKey;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{'" + sortKey + '\'' + ":'" + name + "\'}";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
> Task :Test.main()
Expected order: c -> b -> a -> d
Unsorted order: a -> b -> c -> d
Sorted order: [{'c':'name_c'}, {'b':'name_b'}, {'a':'name_a'}, {'d':'name_d'}]
Sorted order in Array: [{'c':'name_c'}, {'b':'name_b'}, {'a':'name_a'}, {'d':'name_d'}]
```